# How to display the two arrays as the instructions stated

Tags: java

I'm doing this assignment for my Java course, so the instruction is:

> "Write a program that generates 100 random integers in the range 1 to 100, and stores them in an array. Then, the program should call a class method that extracts the numbers that are even multiplesof4intoanarray and returns the array. The program should then call another method that extracts the numbers that are not even multiples of 4 into a separate array and returns the array. Both arrays should then be displayed."

```
public class Assignment8
{
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    int [] numbers = new int [100];
    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      numbers[i] = (int)(Math.random()*((100)+1))+1; 
    }
      int EMO4N [] = evenMultiplesOf4(numbers);
      System.out.println("The even multiples of four are: ");
      for (int m = 8; m < EMO4N.length; m++) {
        System.out.println(EMO4N [m] + "  " ); 
      }
      int NEMO4N [] = nonEvenMultiplesOf4(numbers);
      System.out.println("The numbers that are not even multiples of four are: ");
      for (int k = 1; k < NEMO4N.length; k++) {
        System.out.println(NEMO4N [k] + "  ");
      }
  }
  public static int [] evenMultiplesOf4(int [] numbers) 
  {
    int EMO4 = 8;
    for (int x : numbers) {
      if (x % 4 == 0 & (x / 4) % 2 == 0) {
        EMO4++;
      }
    }
    int [] EMO4N = new int [EMO4];
    int y = 8;
    for (int m : numbers) {
      if(y % 4 == 0 & (y / 4) % 2 == 0) {
        EMO4N[y] = m;
        y++;
      }
    }
    return EMO4N;
  }

  public static int [] nonEvenMultiplesOf4( int [] numbers)
  {
    int NEMO4 = 1;
    for (int j : numbers) {
      if (j % 4 != 0 || (j / 4) % 2 != 0) {
        NEMO4++;
      }
    }
    int [] NEMO4N = new int [NEMO4];
    int k = 1;
    for (int n : numbers) {
      if(k % 4 != 0 || (k / 4) % 2 != 0) {
        NEMO4N[k] = n;
        k++;
      }
    }
    return NEMO4N;
  }
}
```

The result displayed is​ always a combination of 0s and some other random numbers.

Comment: Why do you start `m` and `y` off at `8`?

Comment: `(int)(Math.random()*((100)+1))+1` that generates values out of range because [1..101]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several small logic errors.

1. You start `m` and `y` off at `8`, which doesn't make sense as they are meant to keep track of the index that you will be inserting at.
2. You use the expression `if (x % 4 == 0 & (x / 4) % 2 == 0)` to determine if the number is divisible by four, but `if(x % 4 == 0)` is sufficient.
3. In your loops:

```
for (int n : numbers) {
    if(k % 4 != 0) {
       NEMO4N[k] = n;
       k++;
    }
}
```

You are checking to see if `k` is divisible by four, when you should be checking `n`. Change it to:

```
for (int n : numbers) {
    if(n % 4 != 0) {
      NEMO4N[k] = n;
      k++;
    }
}
```

I won't provide working code as this seems to be a homework assignment.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking that (x%4==0 & (x/4)%2==0) probably gives the Even multiples of four that's why I put the '&'

Comment: Why would you need  `(x/4)%2==0`? Odd number cannot be divisible by 4 as it would be divisible by 2 making it even number.....

Answer (score 0):

Here is working solution - requires Java8.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    List c1 = generateArray(100);
    Divisors divisors = getDivisors(c1, 4);
    print("Even", divisors.evens);
    print("Odd", divisors.odds);
}

private static void print(String what, List<Integer> items) {
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",");
    items.stream().map(String::valueOf).forEach(joiner::add);
    System.out.println(what + " divisors are: " + joiner.toString());
}

private static Divisors getDivisors(List<Integer> c1, int i) {
    Divisors divisors = new Divisors();
    divisors.value = i;
    c1.stream()
            .filter(value->value>=i)// it is not dividable, so ill skip
            .forEach(value -> {
        int modulo = value % i;
        List<Integer> arr = modulo == 0 ? divisors.evens : divisors.odds;
        arr.add(value);
    });
    return divisors;
}

private static List<Integer> generateArray(int size) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1,100).limit(size).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
}

static class Divisors {
    int value;
    List<Integer> evens = new LinkedList<>();
    List<Integer> odds = new LinkedList<>();
}
```

example output:

```
Even divisors are: 4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40,44,48,52,56,60,64,68,72,76,80,84,88,92,96,100
Odd divisors are: 5,6,7,9,10,11,13,14,15,17,18,19,21,22,23,25,26,27,29,30,31,33,34,35,37,38,39,41,42,43,45,46,47,49,50,51,53,54,55,57,58,59,61,62,63,65,66,67,69,70,71,73,74,75,77,78,79,81,82,83,85,86,87,89,90,91,93,94,95,97,98,99
```